# Ruby uri parsing: "parent path"

Tags: ruby, parsing, uri

I have a URI of the form "http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/quux/". I want to retrieve "http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/". In other words, I want to drop the final segment of the path. What is the idiomatic Ruby way to do this? With a URI library? Or do I just have to write up the string parsing myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most simple way is:

```
File.dirname 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/quux/'
=> "http://example.com/foo/bar/baz"
```

Comment: Is there a way that preserves the trailing slash?

Comment: Don't think so :/. Add `+ '/'` (?)

Comment: Yeah, I ended up with `#{File.dirname(uri)}/`. Wish there was a dedicated method to return the normalized parent URI path.